# I click on just one button's of element, but every button fires on All elements Automatically

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php $q=mysql_query("select * from        comments);
While($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))

{?>
```

One button and A textbox here for when i click the button then the textbox will show up.. And this is the loop section,,, and this work is to be done with jquery,,

```
$(".button").click(function(){
$(".textbox").show();
});
```

After execution of code! I have 10buttons that is created by loop contruct with php while... When i click ones the button to show the textbox.. All buttons are clicked at same time,, and all textbox are shown at same time automatically,, why? So wht should i do guyz?

Comment: Show the part where html is generated... You're probably using the same button/textbox classes for all of the buttons.

Comment: Dear bro, i have written one button and a texbox in loop! And even one class for button as .button and .text for textbox.. But suppose that,, whlie loop has created the both of elemets for many times. Then i click on just first button.. All textbox comes out only just one button click event. Thts all i want to ask! Why is that and whts the solution is?

Comment: Because `$(".textbox").show();` finds all elements with the class `textbox` and then executes `show()` on all of them. Either create different classes for each of them (example: https://jsfiddle.net/71ko8p2r/) or try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple rows and each row has a button and textbox and all of them have .button and .textbox classes then you have to write your jQuery code little differently.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".textbox").show();
});
```

The thing is that in your code click on any element with class .button will result in showing all the elements with .textbox class. In modified version when you click button then we are using $(this) to address exactly the button that was clicked and then searching for the textbox closest to this particular button. But it depends on your html structure.

Comment: I doubt that the textbox is a parent of the button, as it seems to be hidden by default ... `next` instead of `closest` might work.

Comment: That's why we need to see the html, otherwise we can just make predictions.  The main point is that $(this) should be used to address the exact element that was clicked and use it as an starting point to search for appropriate textbox which should be shown.

Comment: Dear bro, i have written one button and a texbox in loop! And even one class for button as .button and .text for textbox.. But suppose that,, whlie loop has created the both of elemets for many times. Then i click on just first button.. All textbox comes out only just one button click event. Thts all i want to ask! Why is that and whts the solution is?

Comment: That is exactly your problem that you have a lot of elements with the same class and that is why all of them are shown when you click the button. The solution is to use $(this) to find out which button was clicked exactly and then find the .textbox element nearest to this button, which was clicked.